# Рандомайзер слов для сайта

Tags: html

У меня к вам есть просьба. Я хочу сделать некий рандомайзер на сайте, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она выдала какой-то ответ. Ответы я хочу сам задать программе чтобы она выбрала и выдала одну из них.Помогите пожалуйста сделать.Я использую Sublime text но вы предлагайте свои варианты. Заранее спасибо )

Comment: Создайте массив с ответами и генерируйте случайное число (от 0 до кол-ва ответов) и просто выводите элемент массив (ответ) под индексом равным этому числу.

Comment: *Я использую Sublime text но вы предлагайте свои варианты.* это вообще к чему ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, =) звучит как "А Вы на чем кодите на sublime или блокноте?" ))

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать что-то в этом роде

```
let data = [
        'str1',
        'str2',
        'str3',
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *data.length);

console.log( data[ randomNumber ] );
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]